# NullPointerException while testing Spring boot camel application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

```
public class MyRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.scan("com.mypackage.routes");
        ctx.refresh();
        return ctx;
    }
    @Test
    public void testRouteRunning() throws Exception {
       assertTrue(context().getRouteStatus("direct:start").isStarted());
    }
}
```

getRouteStatus is returning null I am following [this](https://github.com/mzimecki/MySpringBootCamelExample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mzimecki/camel/spring/route/HelloRouteTest.java) to write my test cases

Any pointers on how to fix this will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you know whether the route name is correct? What does the javadoc say wrt getRouteStatus(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the id of the route, not the url, eg "direct:start" is the url of the route, the route has an id as well. If you do not specify an id, then an id is auto assigned such as `route1`, `route2` etc.

Use `.routeId("myNameHere")` to specify the id of a route.